# How to implement long running queries on IdhttpServer?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, indy10

What is good way to implement long running queries on IdHttpServer. I have written simple logic to do so, please advise suggest better way to achive the same as I'm struggling with its performance. 
I am using D2010 and Indy 10.5.8 to achieve the goal, also suggest if we retrive values frequently from session will that be a resource intensive ?

```
procedure TForm1.ServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
   SessionObj : TSessionData;
begin
 if ARequestInfo.Document = 'EXECUTEQUERY' then
 begin
   if not Assigned(ARequestInfo.Session.Content) then
   begin
      SessionObj := TSessionData.Create;
      ARequestInfo.Session.Content.AddObject('U_SESSION', SessionObj);
      SessionObj.RunLongQuery;
   end;
 end;

 if ARequestInfo.Document = 'GETDATA' then
 begin
   SessionObj := TSessionData(ARequestInfo.Session.Content.Objects[ ARequestInfo.Session.Content.IndexOf('U_SESSION')]);
   if SessionObj.GetQueryStat = Done  then
    begin
       AResponseInfo.ContentStream.CopyFrom(SessionObj.GetMemStream, SessionObj.GetMemStream.Size);
       SessionObj.GetMemStream.Clear;
       AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
    end else if SessionObj.GetQueryStat = Error then
        AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 500
    else AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 102;
 end;

end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSessionEnd(Sender: TIdHTTPSession);
begin
  TSessionData(Sender.Content.Objects[ Sender.Content.IndexOf('U_SESSION')]).Free;
end;

{ TProcessQuery }

constructor TProcessQuery.Create;
begin
  myConn := TMyConnection.Create(nil);
  myConn.LoginPrompt := False;
  myConn.UserName := 'UserName';
  myConn.Password := 'Password';
  myConn.Server := 'Host';
  myConn.Database := 'DBName';
  myConn.Connected := True;
  myQuery := TMyQuery.Create(nil);
  myQuery.Unidirectional := True;
  myQuery.Options.CreateConnection := False;
  myQuery.Connection := myConn;
  Fstat := None;
  Fstream := TMemoryStream.Create;
end;

destructor TProcessQuery.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(myConn) then begin
    myConn.Close;
    myConn.Disconnect;
    FreeAndNil(myConn);
  end;
end;

procedure TProcessQuery.ExecuteQuery;
begin
  Status := Started;
  myQuery.SQL.Text := '<Some Query>';
  myQuery.Open;
  try
    try
    while not myQuery.Eof do
    begin
         Status := Inprogress;
         //Add to FStream which would be returned to user.
    end;
    except
        on Exception do
        Status := Error;
    end;
  finally
    myQuery.Close;
  end;
end;

{ TSessionData }

constructor TSessionData.Create;
begin
  FProcessQuery :=  TProcessQuery.Create;
end;

function TSessionData.GetMemStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  result := FProcessQuery.Fstream;
end;

function TSessionData.GetQueryStat: TStatus;
begin
  result := FProcessQuery.Status;
end;

procedure TSessionData.RunLongQuery;
begin
  FProcessQuery.ExecuteQuery
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running the actual query in the context of `ServerCommandGet()`, so the client will not receive a reply until the query has finished.  For what you are attempting, you need to move the query to its own thread and let `ServerCommandGet()` exit so the client gets a reply and can move on, thus freeing it to send subsequent `GETDATA` requests.  In `ServerSessionEnd()`, you will have to terminate the query thread if it is still running, and free the `TSessionData` object.

There are some other problems with your code as well.

`ServerCommandGet()` is checking for `not Assigned(ARequestInfo.Session.Content)` and then calling `ARequestInfo.Session.Content.AddObject()` when `ARequestInfo.Session.Content`is nil.  I don't see any code that is creating the `ARequestInfo.Session.Content` object.

If the client issues multiple `EXECUTEQUERY` requests, you are storing them all in `AResponseInfo.Session.Content` using the same name, 'U_SESSION'.  `GETDATA` will return the results of only the first query it finds, and `ServerSessionEnd()` only frees the first query it finds.  So either give each query a unique name and send that back to the client so it can include it in `GETDATA` and make `ServerSessionEnd()` loop through the entire `Sender.Content`, or else do not allow multiple queries in the same HTTP session.  If the client issues a new `EXECUTEQUERY` while a previous query is still active, kill the previous query before starting the new one.

When the client issues `GETDATA`, the code needs to take into account that the requested query may not exist, such as if it previously expired and was freed by `ServerSessionEnd()`.  Also, if a query does exist and has finished, you are calling `AResponseInfo.ContentStream.CopyFrom()` but `AResponseInfo.ContentStream` is nil when `ServerCommandGet()` is called.  You are responsible for providing your own `ContentStream` object.  So either take ownership of `TSessionData`'s memory stream and assign it as the `AResponseInfo.ContentStream` object, or else create a new `TMemoryStream` to copy into and then assign that as the `AResponseInfo.ContentStream` object.  Either way, `TIdHTTPServer` will free the `AResponseInfo.ContentStream` after sending it to the client.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistakes, now I'm executing query in a separate thread and corrected the assignement in GETDATA part. I am calling GETDATA after an interval of 500ms to check for the status can I lower that value to 100ms or so, just a note i'm not using keepalive will the server work proper.  I'm expecting 50-60 client connected simultaneously and a total of more than 500 clients

Comment: Yes, you server will work fine without keepalives. HTTP is not a stateful protocol, it is designed to allow for disconnects between requests. That is where (cookie-based) sessions come into play, to persist information between requests and connections.